# Which versions of windows generate local crash dump files through its error reporting? Which do not?

Tags: windows, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I'm writing a Java class to pull the version # of Windows from the registry, and then using this number to determine whether or not I need to create registry values to create a local dump. If not I need to know where to look for the dump files. Which versions of windows already have this feature through Watson or anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to trap the dump file locally?

Comment: Yes, for those versions of windows that don't do that already. Some older versions do via Watson, but I wasn't sure exactly which versions already have this capability or where to find their dumps.

Answer (score 0):

Vista was the first OS to fully embrace the WER system.  With that, several [registry settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx) were made available to configure how Windows Error Reporting would work.  The one(s) you're interested in are the "LocalDumps" keys.  It's an easy task to write a utility program to set these flags including the target folder for the dump files.